# Excel Power Query failing on adding Date Column

Tags: excel, powerquery

So, I have data with a date (`CLOSE_DATE`) / value (`KG_A7`) pair where I am grouping (sum) the value over a month (using the first of the month as the column to group by).  I can do this manually but am trying to write a function (fnGroupByMonth) as I need to do this transformation for different data sources.

I have working code:

```
let 
    fnGroupByMonth = (SourceTable, GroupBy as text, Values as text) =>
    let
        #"Inserted Start of Month" = Table.AddColumn(SourceTable, "Month", each Date.From(Date.StartOfMonth([CLOSE_DATE])), type date),
        #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Inserted Start of Month", {"Month"}, {{Values, each List.Sum([KG_A7]), type number}}),
        #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Month", Order.Ascending}})
    in
        #"Sorted Rows"
in
    fnGroupByMonth
```

But when I try to change (1) `[CLOSE_DATE]` for `Table.Column(SourceTable, GroupBy)` or (2) `[KG_A7]` for `Table.Column(SourceTable, Values)` I get the following errors:

(1) *The Date value must contain the Date component Details:
[List]*

(2) The same sum of Values for each month

I have tried without the `as text` and I have tried sending the column names as columns (so `[CLOSE_DATE]` instead of `"CLOSE_DATE"`, in which case I get the error "*There is an unknown identifier. Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I will confess that I don't understand the usage but I cribbed an answer from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840125) that I've just come across and replaced the `Table.Column(SourceTable, GroupBy)` with `Record.Field(_, GroupBy)` (and the same for `Values`) and it works!  Now I've just got to learn why!!